# cakephp & routes - how to use a GET param in the URL

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have a simple GET form which allows the user to type in a location, then select a couple of other options and perform a search.

So at the minute the url for this action is: 
controller/search?area=london&option1=whatever&option2=whateverelse

I'd like the url to be:
controller/search/london?option1=whatever&option2=whateverelse

so in other words the GET param for the area would be incorporated into the url but not as a NVP.

Is there a way to do this? I'm a bit confused about routing or if there's another way?

Thanks

Comment: Ehm. Create a folder named search and put a page london in it, instead of search? ;)

Comment: But then I'd need a folder for every possible location that might be entered, which could be any city, town or village in the UK

Comment: yup. But it's a way to do it ;) 
Anyway, I would do this in .htaccess url_rewrite..

Comment: You could specify an argument for your search method in the controller: `search($area=null)` this would then assign "london" to $area in your example above.

Comment: @timstermatic how can I pass an argument like that via a GET form? Is it possible?

Comment: I'd make an interim controller action that rebuilds and redirects. do_search() { // rebuild url and redirect as controller/action/town?...}

Comment: @timstermatic that's commonly referred to as the Post-Redirect-Get pattern (PRG).

Comment: @timstermatic thats as AD7six already said PRG. This plugin already implements that concept. https://github.com/CakeDC/search

Comment: @AD7six cheers for the info. I had seen that acronym before and never realised the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Use [routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) and the [CakeDC search plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search). If you do not have yet read about routing you should do it, its a very powerful feature.

```
Route::connect('/search/:city/*', array('controller' => 'search', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('city'), 'city' => 'a-zA-Z0-9_-]+')));
```

Just wrote that down without testing, try it if does not work put some effort into it. This will make the city become the first arg of SearchController::index($city = null);

The search plugin will help you with mapping the query params to search conditions that can be used to retrieve the data from the database, see its readme.md how to do it.